# Why do I get only one Key in Keyset while Overloading Comparable in TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, collections, overloading, treemap

1. I Tried to do custom Ordering in my TreeMap based on length of string. Why am I getting only one Key if the length of the string is same despite being different strings.
2. How do I fix this and what are the implications for the equals meth0d, will it ever be used or will compareTo take its place.

The code:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Student implements Comparable {
    int RollNo;
    String Name;
    public Student(int RollNo, String Name) {
        this.RollNo = RollNo;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        Student str = (Student) arg0;
        return Integer.valueOf(str.Name.length()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(this.Name.length()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Student, Integer> mp = new TreeMap<Student, Integer>();
        mp.put(new Student(1, "Sameer"), 1);
        mp.put(new Student(2, "Aameer"), 2);

        for(Student st : mp.keySet()){
            System.out.println((st.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW: `compareTo` can be wriiten as `return str.Name.length()-this.Name.length();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `compareTo` method compares the lengths of the name `String`s instead of their content, so `Student`s having names with same length are considered identical by the `TreeMap`.

In other words, the `Comparable` or `Comparator` used by the `TreeMap` determines both ordering and uniqueness of the keys.

You can solve the issue by ordering the `TreeMap` by both name length and name content (when the lengths are equal) :

```
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {

    Student str = (Student) arg0;

    int lengthComp = Integer.valueOf(str.Name.length()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(this.Name.length()));
    if (lengthComp == 0) {
        // compare names if the lengths are equal
        return str.Name.compareTo(this.Name);
    } else {
        return lengthComp;
    }
}
```

Besides that, it's better for your class to implement `Comparable<Student>`, which will allow your `compareTo` method to accept a `Student` argument.

> How do I fix this and what are the implications for the equals meth0d, will it ever be used or will compareTo take its place.

`equals` is not used by `TreeMap`, and `compareTo` indeed takes its place.

Answer (score 1):

since compare() returns 0 for both keys, they are considered equal in the sorting. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html to und er stand why it is strictly recommended to habe compare behaving consistent with equals(), but the bottom line is that the second key is not added since it is considered equal to the first.

The solution is to make your compare consistent with equals by adding any kind oft tie breaker. E.g., if the two strings are not equal, but habe the same length, return their lexicographic order, or compute a hash based in the actual characters.

Comment: So we need to override equals over here?? ow does this effect equals behaviour, will equal never be called?

Comment: equals() ist never called in this case, but it's a standard recommendation to assert that a.equals(b) == (a.compare(b)==0) to avoid inconsistent behavior. In you overrode equals() here, nothing would change, but it would become more obvious that you consider the two keys equal.

Answer (score 0):

Length of string for both "Shameer" and "Aameer" are same. So java compareTo method will consider both value (considering length) are same. So both object are considered equal in sorting.

While adding a object to key in Map interface the value should be unique this violated the compareTo method. So not able to add the above values.

> As you already aware that in Map interface duplicate keys is not
>   allowed.

I have explained with the simple example. If key value are same then you cannot add the values into Map interface.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Student2  {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Integer> mp = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    mp.put("Sameer", 1);
    mp.put("Sameer", 2);

    for(String st : mp.keySet()){
        System.out.println((st));
    }
}
}
```

> Result: Sameer

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in TreeMap.put.  With your override of compareTo method the second put does only replace the value for the key because the two strings have same length.